# Java - How to import : ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).addDataType("geometry", Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));

Tags: java, database, postgresql, postgis

I try to import PGgeometry but I have somme error :

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'PGConnection'
```

My model :

```
import java.lang.*;
import org.postgis.*;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "rectangle", schema = "aaa")
public class test {

    java.sql.Connection conn;
    ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).addDataType("geometry", Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));

}
```

I need to import PGgeometry because the type of my column in my data base is geometry (postgis)

Comment: Did you add the PostgreSQL JDBC driver jar file to the classpath?

Comment: no I don't. We can't import it from mvn central ?

Comment: Sure you can. Did you?